# Carrierwave - undefined method `exists?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

What's the best way to check whether the user selected a file for upload in the controller? At the moment I have -

```
def create
 if @object.foo.file.exists?
   do something to object
 end

 if @object.save etc.
```

But this returns 'undefined method `exists?' for nil:NilClass'

In the console, 'exists?' works where it returns true, but throws the error when it should return false. I've tried 'object.save' before querying 'exists?' but it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the rail guides:](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)

> The object in the params hash is an instance of a subclass of IO. Depending on the size of the uploaded file it may in fact be a StringIO or an instance of File backed by a temporary file. In both cases the object will have an original_filename attribute containing the name the file had on the user's computer and a content_type attribute containing the MIME type of the uploaded file.
>
> If the user has not selected a file the corresponding parameter will be an empty string.

So you could start by checking if your param is an empty string.

Hope this helps.